# AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50012: Client assertion is not within its valid time range

Tags: java, azure

I am using Microsoft Java SDK to connect to Azure cloud.

I have created a certificate (p12 file) from .crt,.key & root.crt.
I have uploaded the .crt under Azure AD>App Registrations >Settings>Upload public key.

After that from my Java code I tried to get Azure client (Authenticate) by passing p12 content and password to below API:

```
ApplicationTokenCredentials credentials = new ApplicationTokenCredentials();
public ApplicationTokenCredentials(String clientId, String domain, byte[] certificate, String password, AzureEnvironment)

Azure azure = Azure.authenticate(credentials).withSubscription(SUBSCRIPTION_ID);
```

The above call is successful. But if we try to get `azure.networks()` or `azure.storage()` it fails with below error:

> AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50012: Client assertion is not within its valid time range.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Certificate credentials for application authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-certificate-credentials), after upload the Public Key.

We also need to update the manifest

> In the Azure app registration for the client application, open the application manifest, and replace the keyCredentials property with your new certificate information using the following schema:

```
"keyCredentials": [
    {
        "customKeyIdentifier": "$base64Thumbprint",
        "keyId": "$keyid",
        "type": "AsymmetricX509Cert",
        "usage": "Verify",
        "value":  "$base64Value"
    }
]
```

If cert is not manditory, we also could generate the secret with azure portal. After that we could get ApplicationTokenCredentials with follow way

```
public ApplicationTokenCredentials(String clientId,
                                   String domain,
                                   String secret,
                                   AzureEnvironment environment)
```

Note: If we want to access the Azure resource,we also need to assgin  [Azure AD application to role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#assign-application-to-role).